# Not able to render heatmap using heatmap.js

Tags: javascript, html, heatmap

I want to make a project where I can display the different sensor values from differens sensors in a room on a heatmap. The sensor values are stored in a MySQL database, and I want to use the heatmap.js library for the visualisation of this heatmap.

I used an example project from the library creator himself, but I am not able to render it and I just see my header and footer. What am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>

<body>

<?php
include_once ('header.php');
?>

<main>

<script src="heatmap.js"></script>

<div class="heatmap"></div>

<script>

    // minimal heatmap instance configuration
    var heatmapInstance = h337.create({
      // only container is required, the rest will be defaults
      container: document.querySelector('.heatmap')
    });

    // now generate some random data
    var points = [];
    var max = 0;
    var width = 840;
    var height = 400;
    var len = 200;

    while (len--) {
        var val = Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
        max = Math.max(max, val);
        var point = {
            x: Math.floor(Math.random()*width),
        y: Math.floor(Math.random()*height),
        value: val
      };
      points.push(point);
    }
    // heatmap data format
    var data = {
        max: max,
      data: points
    };
    // if you have a set of datapoints always use setData instead of addData
    // for data initialization
    heatmapInstance.setData(data);

</script>

</main>

<?php
include_once ('footer.php');
?>

</body>
```

Comment: Do you have any console error? How are you accessing the page? Because if you're accessing the html file locally and directly from your browser, it might not be allowed to access the `heatmap.js` file

Comment: no console error, and I access the page on a server. The heatmap.js file is located in the same folder on the same server.

Comment: Can you share the url?

Comment: http://localhost:1234/Heatmap.php and the heatmap.js file is stored on http://localhost:1234/heatmap.js